# How to get images and datas from Marvel API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I got a problem using Marvel API. I am working with ReactJs. Actually, i have succeed in the first step : fetching all the data i wanted on a first page. Using routers, i want, when i click on an image, to build another page with the comic's informations. But, i dont know how to do that. And the real problem is how to get the images, because it seems they are using a different path from the data :
https://developer.marvel.com/documentation/images

here is the code of my first page (working very well) :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from '../Header';
import Searchbar from '../SearchBar';
import ComicThumb from '../ComicThumb';
import { API_URL, API_KEY, HASH, BACKDROP_SIZE } from '../helpers';
import ThreeColGrid from '../ThreeColGrid';

class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    comics: [],
    currentPage: 0,
    totalPages: 0,
    loading: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const endpoint = `${API_URL}public/comics?ts=1&apikey=${API_KEY}&hash=${HASH}&limit=30&offset=${this.state.currentPage}`;
    this.fetchItems(endpoint);
  }

  fetchItems = endpoint => {
    fetch(endpoint)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.setState({
          comics: [...this.state.comics, ...result.data.results],
          currentPage: result.data.offset,
          totalPages: result.data.total,
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { comics } = this.state;

    const images = comics.map(
      res =>
        `${res.thumbnail.path}/${BACKDROP_SIZE}.${res.thumbnail.extension}`,
    );

    console.table(images);

    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Searchbar />

        <ThreeColGrid>
          {this.state.comics.map((i, element) => {
            return (
              <ComicThumb
                clickable={true}
                key={element}
                image={images[element]}
                comicId={i.id}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ThreeColGrid>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

and i have a comic info component, well, which is where the problems are, because i dont know how to gt the datas :

```
import React from 'react';
import ComicThumb from '../ComicThumb';
import { POSTER_SIZE } from '../helpers';

const ComicInfo = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <ComicThumb
            where i want my images to be stocked
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>title</h1>
          <h3>resume</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComicInfo;
```

If anyone can help me with that, it will be great. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ne need help anymore, i found the solution to get every data i wanted.
For thoose who may need help later :
My comicPage Component is like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { API_URL, API_KEY, HASH, BACKDROP_SIZE, POSTER_SIZE } from '../helpers';
import ComicInfo from '../ComicInfo';

class ComicPage extends Component {
  state = {
    comic: [],
    loading: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: false });
    const endpoint = `${API_URL}public/characters/${this.props.match.params.comicId}?ts=1&apikey=${API_KEY}&hash=${HASH}`;
    this.fetchItems(endpoint);
  }

  fetchItems = endpoint => {
    fetch(endpoint)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({ comic: [...this.state.comic, ...result.data.results] });
        console.log(result);
        console.table(result);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { comic } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        {/* le composant parent lui donne ses props */}
        <ComicInfo comic={comic} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default ComicPage;
```

And then, in a comicInfo component, i justed put the props :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { API_URL, API_KEY, HASH, BACKDROP_SIZE, POSTER_SIZE } from '../helpers';
import ComicThumb from '../ComicThumb';

const ComicInfo = props => {
  const images = props.comic.map(
    res => `${res.thumbnail.path}/${POSTER_SIZE}.${res.thumbnail.extension}`,
  );
  const background = props.comic.map(res => `${res.description}`);
  return (
    <div>
      {props.comic.map(res => (
        <h1>Character Name : {res.name}</h1>
      ))}
      <img src={images} alt="test" />
      <h3>Résumé : {background}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComicInfo;
```

It's not finished, but i know now how to end this project :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to add some props like that :

```
      <ComicThumb image={props.character} />
      <h1>{props.character.name}</h1>
      <ComicInfo />
```

but it doesn't work, i am completely lost. If anyone as an idea, i'll take it. I think i have to construct the image path with the id, but i really don't know how to take the ID from the URL. Or if there is another way to get that bloody Id.

Answer (score 0):

First, add [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) to your project to manage routing:

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

Import `react-router` into the Home component:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Import the ComicInfo component as well:

```
import ComicInfo from './components/ComicInfo' // update location as I don't know where this component resides
```

Define the routes of your application in the Home component:

```
  render() {
    const { comics } = this.state;

    const images = comics.map(
      res =>
        `${res.thumbnail.path}/${BACKDROP_SIZE}.${res.thumbnail.extension}`,
    );

    return (
      <Router>
          <Switch>
              <Route path="/comic-info" component={ComicInfo} />
              <Route path="/">
                  <div>
                      <Header />
                      <Searchbar />

                      <ThreeColGrid>
                          // note that the arguments for the map function are first the `element`, then the `index`
                          {this.state.comics.map((element, index) => {
                              return (
                                  // Wrap each thumbnail with a <Link> component
                                  <Link 
                                      key={index}
                                      to={{
                                      pathname: '/comic-info',
                                      state: {
                                          selectedComic: element, // pass each comic in the state of each <Link>
                                      }
                                  }}>
                                      <ComicThumb
                                          clickable={true}
                                          image={images[index]}
                                          comicId={element.id}
                                      />
                                  </Link>
                              );
                          })}
                      </ThreeColGrid>
                  <div/>
             </Route>
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

In ComicInfo, you can now access the `selectedComic` field as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ComicThumb from '../ComicThumb';
import { POSTER_SIZE } from '../helpers';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class ComicInfo extends Component {

render() {
    // Any component wrapped in `<Route>` will receive a `location` prop with an optional `state` field
    const selectedComic = this.props.location.state.selectedComic;

    if (!selectedComic) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
        <Link to="/">
          <span>Back to all comics</span>
        </Link>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ComicThumb
            where i want my images to be stocked
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>{selectedComic.title}</h1>
          <h3>resume</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ComicInfo;
```

One drawback of this implementation is that the user will always have to go through the homepage in order to access a specific comic. In other words, if the user tries to access "/comic-info" directly, they will be redirected to the homepage.

You can get around this by creating a more specific path such as "comic-info/{comic-id}" and then fetching the data for that specific comic in the component's `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle method.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Actually, i have already defined routes in my app component, i should have you :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import ComicPage from './ComicPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
          <Route path="/:comicId" component={ComicPage} exact />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my comicPage Component i coded today :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { API_URL, API_KEY, HASH, POSTER_SIZE } from '../helpers';
import ComicInfo from '../ComicInfo';
import ComicThumb from '../ComicThumb';

class ComicPage extends Component {
  state = {
    comic: null,
    loading: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: false });
    const endpoint = `${API_URL}public/characters/${this.props.match.comicId}?ts=1&apikey=${API_KEY}&hash=${HASH}`;
    this.fetchItems(endpoint);
  }

  fetchItems = endpoint => {
    fetch(endpoint)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({ comic: result });
        console.log(result);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ComicThumb />

        <ComicInfo />

        <p>eventuellement après : le prix d'origine et l'année</p>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default ComicPage;
```

So my URL indicates the Id of my comics (my character actually, because the main page shows character and when you click on one, it redirect you to the character pae, well, so i want but i just can't)
I think everything has to be handle in the ComicInfo component, images and regular info but i just don't know how :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { API_URL, API_KEY, HASH, BACKDROP_SIZE } from '../helpers';
import ComicThumb from '../ComicThumb';

const ComicInfo = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <ComicThumb /> */}
      <h1>nom du personnage : {props.Character.description}</h1>
      <h3>Résumé</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComicInfo;
```

Plus, the marvel API is weird, there is no particular path for images, if i understood, you need to access the thumbnail and the extension everytime. It's a little bit weird. I've never seen that before. Usually, there is a specific path for the images. Or maybe i have gone wrong all the time lol.